# Values with Redux-Form return null

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, redux-form

im work with Redux and React, in CRUD operations with API , `createPost` return null into the values of `title`, `categories`, and `content` with Redux-Form?

I could help, I do not know what my mistake ?

**actions file index.js**

```
export const CREATE_POST = 'CREATE_POST';
const URL = 'http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api';
const API_KEY = '1234557';

export function createPost(props) {
const request = axios
  .post(`${URL}/posts?${API_KEY}`, props)
  .then( res => { console.log(res) })
  return {
    type: CREATE_POST,
    payload: request,
  };
}
```

**component file newPost.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import {crearPost} from '../acciones/index';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
class NuevoPost extends React.Component {
    onSubmit(values) {
        this.props.crearPost(values)


    }
    render() { 

        const {fields: {
            title, categories, content} , 
            handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={
                handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
                <h3>Crea un nuevo Post.</h3>
                <div className='form-group'>
                    <label 
                    >titulo</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text' 
                    className='form-control'
                    {...title}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className='form-group'>
                    <label 
                    >Categoria</label>
                    <input 
                    type='text' 
                    className='form-control'
                    {...categories}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className='form-group'>
                    <label 
                    >Contenido</label>
                    <textarea 
                    type='text' 
                    className='form-control'
                    {...content}
                    />
                </div>
                <button 
                type="submit" 
                className="btn btn-info"
                >Postear</button>

            </form>
        )
    }
}


export default reduxForm({
 form: 'newPost',  
 fields: ['title', 'categories', 'content']
})(connect(null, { crearPost })(NuevoPost));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `redux-form` [`Field`](https://redux-form.com/7.4.0/docs/api/field.md/) here

```
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';

<div className='form-group'>
  <label>Categoria</label>
  <Field
    type='text' 
    className='form-control'
    component={'input'}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ashish, the documentation is different in the latest versions..